# Google cloud printers added via "Connect a printer that’s not cloud-ready" option not working

Tags: google-chrome, printing, printer, google-cloud-print

I have 2x printers (HP t520 via LAN), (Canon IX8700 via USB) connected to my Desktop Computer (iMac).

Neither of these printers are by themselves Google Cloud Print enabled.

But because they are connected to the Desktop Computer and for 99% of the time the Desktop Computer is on / in sleep mode, i have set it up on google cloud print using the "Connect a printer that’s not cloud-ready" option as outlined here : https://support.google.com/cloudprint/answer/1686197?hl=en

This setup fine, but soon after setting it up, the 2 printers i added are showing as offline (see below screenshot), despite my Desktop computer currently being on, and despite my desktop computer currently being able to print to either printer via LAN or USB (as applicable).

Any ideas why the cloud print feature via "Connect a printer that’s not cloud-ready" is not working ?

[image: cloud print screenshot]

Comment: Did the printers ever work initially? If they did, what happened in-between? The foremost reasons for printers becoming offline are: Computer entered sleep, printer or computer IP address changed, printer was restarted. If any of the above happened, you will have to redo the Google Cloud Print registration process again. The conditions for this working are so tough that I'm not sure you would like to go through with it. See also [this link](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-fix-the-dreaded-google-cloud-printer-offline-issue/).

Comment: Check also the two registration methods described in the article [Google Cloud Printing for Mac](https://support.shippingeasy.com/hc/en-us/articles/203562729-Google-Cloud-Printing-for-Mac-).

Comment: @harrymc i tried the above, but could still not get it to work, in the end ive setup a VPN to the site and added the printer as an IP printer. Its not the most semantic solution, but seems pretty robust. I would have liked to use google cloud print as from an end users point of view its pretty simple, could not get it to work, if the printers are already google cloud print enabled though (the ones im using are not) google cloud print seems to work fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several possible reasons this could be happening. I will walk you through a whole bunch of troubleshooting steps because I don't have enough information to narrow down your specific issue.

harrymc's response outlines issues such as the computer going to sleep and IP address changes (the latter doesn't affect my cloud printers because I have DHCP set up on my network, like most home users), and printer power cycling. None of these things require me to redo my registration, but your mileage may vary.

One thing that will cause your issue to happen is if Google Chrome is closed. There is a setting in advanced -> system -> continue running background apps when Chrome is closed, and this service must be running for Google cloud print to work correctly. If you shut down chrome and it doesn't continue to run in the background (on the printer host computer), your printer will go offline.

If you turned off the Chrome launch on startup, you may also run into this issue. Check your task manager -> startup to see if launching Chrome on startup is disabled.

I recently had the same issue you are describing because I had registered the same printer in multiple accounts. For whatever reason, Chrome doesn't like this. I had to delete the printer from both accounts, then set up the printer connection again from chrome://devices/.

Sometimes, in order to activate the printer correctly, I had to disconnect all devices from a particular account first (and any other accounts the printer was connected to), then reconnect the printer I want to use.

Another possible cause is that you have a corrupted install of Google Chrome. Doing a clean reinstall of Chrome would fix the issue in this case, since connected devices is a locally stored piece of information.

Another cause could be that you have faulty printer drivers. If you haven't already, uninstall your existing printer drivers from device manager (if on windows) and from system preferences (if on mac) and then find the correct drivers from the manufacturer's website and install them. You'll usually need to remove and re-add chrome connected printers after a driver reinstall.

A couple more considerations to make sure of:

- You must be printing from Google Chrome (or Android) and logged in to an account that has access to use the printer.
- The printer must be on the same sub net as the computer.
- If you want to print from another browser, don't. =) If you have to for some reason, and if you’re using Windows, install [the Google Cloud Print Windows Driver](https://tools.google.com/dlpage/cloudprintdriver). You can use it to print from other web browsers (like Internet Explorer) or computer programs (like Microsoft Office). I know you have a mac, but I've included this for completeness.

Comment: @Sam Can you share what ended up doing the trick so that others can benefit from your experience?